# Eclipse provides Java API browsing but how can one search Java API for a class name or member name?

Tags: java, eclipse

For example how can I use eclipse to search a .jar API for a public member containing a specific word in its name?

Comment: Answering myself: From the top menu select Search->Java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's for a Class name, the easiest way is to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to bring up the "Navigate to Type" dialog. You then get a cool filtered search dialog with every indexed type name that you can find stuff from.